# Include Twig template which Extends

Tags: symfony, twig

I am rendering a `Twig` template as below:

```
$this->render('base.html.twig');
```

The content (simplified) of this `Twig` template looks as below:

```
{% block headers %}
...
{% endblock %}
{% block pagecontent %}
...

    {# I want to include another template (A) here #}
    {# I want to include another template (B) here #}

{% endblock %}
{% block footers %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

I have another `Twig` template which I am not rendering, but I want to include in the above template (where I have placed my `Twig` comment).  The content is as follows:

```
{% extends '::base' %}
{% block headers %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block pagecontent %}
{{ parent() }}
...
{% endblock %}
```

I want to eventually render several `Twig` templates inside of `base.html.twig`.

Is what I am attempting to do achievable, and if so, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to render child template (the one extending `base.html.twig`).

Change in your controller:

```
$this->render('child_template_extending_base.html.twig');
```

Replace `child_template_extending_base` with your real template name.

You can also `embed` another controllers views in your template with this code:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',
    { 'max': 3 }
)) }}
```

Read more about this feature here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: Yeah, this would work but I want to eventually include more than one additional template in `base.html.twig`.  Should probably have made that clear.

Comment: This works, but only if I do not override `block` sections in the `extends` `Twig` template.

Comment: yes - `render` can't override any part of theme - it will be just injected in place where you call it. Read more about inheritance here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I am attempting to include a child `twig` template which `extends` its `parent` inside the `parent`?

Answer (score 0):

base.html.twig

```
{% block headers %}
...
{% endblock %}
{% block pagecontent %}
...

{# I want to include another template (A) here #}
{# I want to include another template (B) here #}

{% endblock %}
{% block footers %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

Your controller:

```
$this->render('base.html.twig');
```

Normally, $this->render('view.html.twig'); accepts only one twig.
If you want to have several templates, you can build it like this:

view.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base' %}
{% block pagecontent %}
    {# Controller function with template 1 #}
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',{ 'max': 3 })) }}
    {# Controller with template 2 #}
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Article:relatedArticles',{ 'max': 4 })) }}
{% endblock %}
```

ANOTHER POSSIBLE SOLUTION IS :
You can break one block into several blocks.